# Proper solution to reduce the number of images created in WP and Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, image-size

I create another WP&Woo theme and i have some doubts about the number of images that are generated by wordpress plus woocommerce.

- Wordpress generate 4 sizes
- Woocommerce generate another 3 sizes
- So we have 7 generated images plus 1 original

Its not hard to count that if we have a eight thousand products:

- WP and Woo will generate 56 thousand images from this
- The number of original images is 8 thousand
- So in total we have **64 thousand images** and in my opinion it's a little disaster

I am looking for the best solution to reduce it, keeping in mind proper functioning and the future of the project

It is not difficult to use `remove_image_size()` but I'm afraid that disabling the default image size is not the right solution.

Another idea that i have is changing images dimensions in Woocommerce to identical with WP ( https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/#section-3 )
At first glance, if i will do that, additional Woo images will not created because they will had the same sizes like WP native images.

Anyway i see a lot of dependencies in all of this so i would like to know yours points of view or any proper solution

Comment: Why not use a plugin for file size reduction, there are plenty of them? Nowadays we need a lot of different sizes of images due to responsiveness and an abundance of screen sizes, and with the help of software and algorithms to reduce the overall file size, it shouldn't then be too difficult. And if its a file structure issue then there are a lot of media library organizers and restructuring plugins and tools to use.

Comment: If I can make a good strategy at the beginning, in my opinion it is better than using another plugin.
And yes you right, many different sizes are helpful, but if you have 7 sizes and couple of them are very similar, I do not think it's useful.